# Recovering Google Fit data from 1970

Tags: android, google-fit

I am coding a small App where I need to retrieve all the data that the user may have recorded since the origin of the times in Google Fit, I tried to pass the unix time of January 01, 1970 in seconds (-3600) but I get an error that it is an invalid date.

My current code:

```
val endTime = getCurrentTime()
val startTime = -3600


val readRequest = DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .aggregate(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: The documentation says that `startTime` is _"A start time, in the given unit since epoch, inclusive."_. Since it says "since" it's at or after the epoch. The value -3600 would be 31st December 1969, 23:00 GMT. Why not use zero? it would be 1st January 1970, 00:00 GMT.

Comment: Hi @MarkusKauppinen! I tried to pass zero value but the error is the same: " java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid start time: 0"

Comment: Maybe you need to define `startTime` as `long` as that what `setTimeRange()` expects. Though I'd expect some other kind of error message if that were the problem.

Comment: Hi @MarkusKauppinen Yes, I tried to define `startTime` as `Long` but the result is the same error.

Comment: I can say with certainty that you don't have fit data anything like as far back as 1970. Try passing in a time for an instant something like 10 years ago.